# How to overlay images with soft edges

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a set of images of some shapes on black backgrounds. I want to overlay these shapes on another image. This is a sample:

```
m = 200; n = m*3/2; p = m / 2;
background = im2double(rgb2gray(imresize(imread('pears.png'), [m, n])));
[x, y] = meshgrid(linspace(-1, 1, 64));
shape1 = imadjust(im2double(imresize(imread('moon.tif'), [m, m])), [.1 .9], [0, 1]);
shape2 = imadjust(im2double(rgb2gray(imresize(imread('saturn.png'), [m, m]))), [.1 .9], [0, 1]);
mask1 = double(shape1>0);
mask2 = double(shape2>0);

I = background;
I(:, (1:m)+0) = (1-mask1).*I(:, (1:m)+0) + mask1.*shape1;
I(:, (1:m)+p) = (1-mask2).*I(:, (1:m)+p) + mask2.*shape2;
```

And the result:

[image]

How can I remove those sharp black edges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can erode your masks slightly with [`imerode`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html) to remove the black edges, then filter them with [`imfilter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html) to blend the images together smoothly. Here's a simple example with disk filters of radius 2:

```
erode1 = imerode(mask1, strel('disk', 2));
erode2 = imerode(mask2, strel('disk', 2));
blend1 = imfilter(erode1, fspecial('disk', 2));
blend2 = imfilter(erode2, fspecial('disk', 2));
I = background;
I(:, (1:m)+0) = (1-blend1).*I(:, (1:m)+0) + blend1.*shape1;
I(:, (1:m)+p) = (1-blend2).*I(:, (1:m)+p) + blend2.*shape2;
```

[image]

To refine the result you can experiment with the types and sizes of the structure elements and filters created by [`strel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/strel-class.html) and [`fspecial`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html), respectively.

Comment: It's way better, but I need to remove the black edge completely. Is it possible?

Comment: @saastn: Updated my answer to address that.

Comment: Thanks, I think `fspecial('gaussian', 2)` makes it even better.